# Update score in MongoDB only if it a higher score

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I've made a game and implemented a leaderboard with a player name and score.

But currently if you get a score of say 5 and play again and get a score of say 3 then the score is updated to 3, but I want the highest score you got to remain.

This is my current code, it finds the user by id and sets the id, name, score.

```
const users = await mongodb.getDb()
  .db('footballers')
  .collection('users')
  .updateOne(
    { _id }, 
    { $set: {_id, name, score } },
    { upsert: true }
  );
```

I tried to add `$max` field as apparently this will only update the field if it higher than the previous but the database never appears to update. I even tried putting `$max` to `0` and got a `score of 1` and nothing happened.

Any ideas? Thanks

```
const users = await mongodb.getDb()
  .db('footballers')
  .collection('users')
  .updateOne(
    { _id }, 
    { $set: {_id, name, score } },
    { $max: { score: 0 } },
    { upsert: true }
  );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're building a leaderboard, you don't need to update the fields `_id` and `name` fields every time you're trying to update the score. For updating the score of a user only when his/her current score is higher than his/her past score, you can pass a less than filter to the `updateOne` query.

```
const users = await mongodb.getDb()
  .db('footballers')
  .collection('users')
  .updateOne(
    { _id, score: { $lt: _score } }, 
    { $set: { score } },
    { upsert: true }
  );
```

Assuming `_score` is the current score you're trying to update in the database. This will only fetch the document from the database where `_id` matches and saved score is less than `_score`.

**Edit**: Above query would give the desired behaviour if you already have documents in `users` collection. In this case, `upsert` will cause duplicate values for `_id`. To achieve what you desire, you can use this:

```
const users = await mongodb.getDb()
  .db('footballers')
  .collection('users')
  .updateOne(
    { _id }, 
    { $set: { _id, name }, $max: { score: _score } },
    { upsert: true }
  );
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for this.

I tested the example and it works well updating the score.

But in terms of me setting the _id and name, this is because if the player is playing the game for the first time I need to set the _id and name at this point, and then after that if they play again I just want to update the score.

I set the _id, name and score at the point the game ends so how would I achieve this but only if it's the first time playing the game?

Comment: One issue with this, this will return a document if it finds a matching _id.

However if one isn't found it will try and create a new document with the same _id resulting in a duplicate _id error, not sure how to resolve this :)

Comment: @JoeConsterdine Please see the edited answer.